# Error SSH in my vks OVH

Tags: ssh, debian

Server : Debian

I haven't acces at my ssh. But if i try restart or start ssh on my kvm with :

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
```

this is error : sh: /tmp/sh: No such file or directory

Why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens if shebang (#!) has an error.
Maybe in your case the file `/etc/init.d/ssh` has:
    `#!/tmp/sh`. 
sh is in `/bin/sh` folder usually.

If you installed openssh server manually you can try to install it using apt or aptitute.
Else try `service ssh start`. You have to be administrator in order to start ssh service.

Comment: I have try : service ssh start but not working . Always : sh: /tmp/sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you were the victim of some exploit? At least in the Virtualmin forums, something like this is being discussed right now:

http://www.virtualmin.com/node/34429

If you create an empty file `/tmp/sh`, you should at least be able to start the service again:

```
echo "" > /tmp/sh
service sshd start
```

But like the people over at the Virtualmin forums, I've never heard of a problem like this. If it's indeed an attack, whatever rootkit they used didn't do a good job.

Comment: This is an year old but we had the same issue on a client's server. An exploit was trying to download a script from an url and to save it in "/tmp/sh" before executing it.
The "missing /tmp/sh file" error was the result of the domain not being alive anymore and the exploit trying to execute the script without checking if the file was successfully downloaded.